# Work done by piston cylinder

Tags: thermodynamics, work, gas

If expansion in the piston cylinder take place, we get the work.
What if this expansion takes place in vacuum; will there be work done by gas?

Comment: A diagram of the piston indicating what regions have vacuum and which are filled with gas would help us understand your question.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Could you [edit](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/766815/edit) to add more details or visual aids?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Free expansion of ideal gas into a vacuum](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/680946/free-expansion-of-ideal-gas-into-a-vacuum).  This is one of many answers on PSE. Search posts containing the wrords,  [ideal gas expansion vacuum](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=ideal+gas+expansion+vacuum).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the piston has no mass the process you are describing is known as a [Joule expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_expansion). The work done in a Joule expansion is zero.

If the piston has a mass then some work will be done as that work will go into the kinetic energy of the piston.

Comment: But if the cylinder is closed on the vacuum end and the piston comes to rest at the closed end, no net work will have been done by the gas.